# Look for leading asterisks using regex in Lua

Tags: regex, lua, special-characters

I'm trying to find out if a string has 06 leading asterisks 
for e.g. 
if the string has "******abc" then pass
if the string has "***abc**" or "**abc" or "*" then fail

I've tried this Online (https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo)

```
s1 = "**"

if (string.match(s1, '^****$')) then
 print "pattern matches"
else
 print "pattern does not match"
end
```

But it does not seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua does not have regular expressions because it is light weight. However the pattern below matches what you are trying to accomplish.

```
s1 = "*******TEST"

if (string.match(s1, '^[*][*][*][*][*][*]')) then
 print "pattern matches"
else
 print "pattern does not match"
end
```

Comment: for a mode modular version use `'^' .. string.rep('[*]', 6)` instead ;)

Answer (score 6):

From [Lua Reference Manual 6.4.1 Patterns:](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1)

> **Character Class:** A character class is used to represent a set of characters. The following combinations are allowed in describing a
>   character class:
>
> x: (where x is not one of the magic characters ^$()%.[]*+-?)
>   represents the character x itself.
>
> ...
>
> %x: (where x is any non-alphanumeric character) represents the character x. This is the standard way to escape the magic characters.

So * is a magic character. Which has to be escaped unless used in a character class like `[*]`.

A pattern that matches any string preceeded by exactly 6 asterisks is `"^%*%*%*%*%*%*[^*]+"`

The `[^*]+` ensures that your remaining string does not contain other asterisks. By matching at least one non-asterisk character.

> [^set]: represents the complement of set, where set is interpreted as
>   above.
>
> ...
>
> a single character class followed by '+', which matches one or more
>   repetitions of characters in the class. These repetition items will
>   always match the longest possible sequence;